# boost spirit string attribute compatibility

Tags: c++, boost-spirit

The title may not be very well expressed. Please comment on the correct technical term.

Today I noticed the following. Given

```
const std::string in( "QWERT" );
std::string out;

boost::spirit::qi::parse( in.begin(), in.end(),
    +boost::spirit::qi::char_, out );

boost::spirit::qi::parse( in.begin(), in.end(),
    +boost::spirit::qi::char_[ boost::phoenix::ref( out ) =
        boost::spirit::_1 ] );

boost::spirit::qi::parse( in.begin(), in.end(),
    boost::spirit::as_string[ +boost::spirit::qi::char_ ]
        [ boost::phoenix::ref( out ) = boost::spirit::_1 ] );
```

the first `parse` extracts the string `QWERT` into `out` as expected. The second only yields the string `T`.

I assume the generated phoenix function gets called on each match of `char_` (which is each character) which means five assignments to `out`, the last being `T`.

Is this the expected behaviour? (Please point me to the relevant section in the boost documentation.)

Currently (I'm using this as a rule in a grammar) I fixed this by the expression in the third `parse`, which looks a little awkward.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is the expected behavior due to [C++ operator precedence](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence). Your second grammar is being evaluated as:

```
+ ( boost::spirit::qi::char_[ boost::phoenix::ref( out ) = boost::spirit::_1 ] )
```

What you were expecting was:

```
(+boost::spirit::qi::char_)[ boost::phoenix::ref( out ) = boost::spirit::_1 ]
```

That second line won't actually work, since (+boost::spirit::qi::char_) is of type `std::vector<char>`, so you need to convert that vector to a string, like your third grammar does.

Comment: Yes, thank you. Getting my mind around spirit lets me forget that it ist still C++ from time to time. I tried the second expression and expected the same magic to kick in that enables parsing into a `std::string` as it does in the first parse call in my examples.